# Редирект с несуществующей страницы на 404

Tags: http-status-code-404

Здравствуйте! Есть строчка в `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ index.php?do=cat&category=$1 [L]
```

Она редиректит с несуществующей страницы вида `https://site.ru/blablabla` на главную. Мне нужно, чтобы перекидывало на страницу ошибки 404. Пробовала сделать так:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ 404.php?do=cat&category=$1 [L]
```

С несуществующей перекидывает на 404, но и категории, которые существуют, перестают отображаться и тоже отдают 404. Сами статьи работают нормально. Подскажите, пжл, код, чтобы и категории показывались, и несуществующие страницы вида `https://site.ru/category/blablabla` и `https://site.ru/blablabla` редиректили на страницу 404. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, самым правильным вариантом будет следующий:

- дополнить код на PHP, чтобы при запросе несуществующей категории или статьи, от сервера возвращался код ошибки 404
- добавить в `.htaccess` строчку:

  ```
  ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
  ```